# List index out of range while removing elements from array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know this is a basic question but here it's weird.

I have no idea why this is giving the error. plz help me with this. Thanks in advance

```
arr = [11,22,33,44,55,66,77]
brr = [1,2,3,4,55]
res_arr = arr

for i in range(len(arr)):
    if arr[i] in brr:
        res_arr.remove(arr[i])
```

Gives me the error List index out of range.

Any clues

**EDIT :**

This helped me solve the error.

`res_arr = list(arr)`

Comment: `res_arr = arr` doesn't copy the list. Hence you're removing the items while iterating on the same list => composite duplicate

Comment: You are removing items from `res_arr` which has the same length as `arr`. As you are removing the items, the list is getting shorter and shorter, hence the error. 

Suppose you have 2 lists of 6 elements. You will then have indexes from 0 to 5.
If you happen to delete an item from the 2nd list, it will be one element short compared to the original one.

Comment: There are 2 ways on countering this : 

* Instead of duplicating the list, and removing the elements. Just create a new one with the elements you wish.

* Duplicate the list, and instead of removing the items from start to end, remove them from end to start, so you won't have the problem of out of bound range.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre is right that you should not remove from a list you are iterating over, however the error in this case is because `remove(item)` does not remove an item with value `item`, but the element at index `item`

Comment: Thanks for the info jesse Bakker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `list comprehension` . It is not a good idea to remove an element while iterating over it. And `res_arr = arr` does not do what you think. You need to look at how to copy objects in python

**Ex:**

```
arr = [11,22,33,44,55,66,77]
brr = [1,2,3,4,55]
print([i for i in arr if i not in brr])
```

**Output:**

```
[11, 22, 33, 44, 66, 77]
```

You can use the copy module to copy objects in python.

**Ex:**

```
import copy
res_arr = copy.deepcopy(arr)
```

Comment: Deleting from a list you are iterating over is indeed bad, and he is not copying the list. However the error he gets is because list.remove(i) removes the element at index i, not the element with value i

Comment: No need for `copy`, it is for more complicated objects. Use `res_arr = list(arr)`.

Comment: He asked `why is my error happening`, not `how do I solve this`. Even if an answer to his problem is good. :)

Comment: mr_mo ,  it helped, thanks.

Comment: Rakesh, Your answer also worked. Thanks.